# Assuming that $a$ and $b$ commute, prove the following.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$ commute.

$b^{-1}a^{-1} = (ab)^{-1} = (ba)^{-1} = a^{-1}b^{-1}.$

---

Prove $a \text { and } b^{-1}$ commute.

$ab = ba$

$b^{-1}ab = b^{-1}ba$

$b^{-1}ab = a$

$(b^{-1}ab)b^{-1} = ab^{-1} $

$b^{-1}a  = ab^{-1} $

---

Prove $a \text { and } ab$ commute.

$ab = ba$

$a(ab) = a(ba)$

$a(ab) = (ab)a$

---

Prove $a^2 \text { and } b^2$ commute.

$ab = ba$

$(ab)^2 = (ba)^2$

$a^2b^2 = b^2a^2$

---

Prove $xax^{-1} \text { and } xbx^{-1}$ commute.

$ab = ba$

$x(a)x^{-1}x(b)x^{-1} = x(b)x^{-1}x(a)x^{-1}$

$xax^{-1}xbx^{-1} = xbx^{-1}xax^{-1}$

---

Prove that $ab = ba \text { iff } aba^{-1} = b$

$\to$

$aba^{-1} = baa^{-1}$

$aba^{-1} = b$

$\leftarrow$

$aba^{-1}a = ba$

$ab = ba$

---

Please, check my work.

Comment: I don't get what you're asking. In the first line, you correctly proved that $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$ commute. What are the remaining $140$ lines you wrote all about?

Comment: you want to prove ab = ba from the fact $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$ commute ?

Comment: If so I have added an answer below

Comment: For the second one, prove that $a$ and $b^{-1}$ commute, for the third one prove that $a$ and $ab$ commute and so on.

Comment: @AbstraktAlgebra Then please, edit your question so people reading it will understand what you mean. By that, I mean that every part should first show what you want to prove, then prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first three and the last two are fine.

The fourth is missing a bit of justification: it’s true that $ab=ba$ implies that $(ab)^2=(ba)^2$, but $(ab)^2=abab$, and you have to make an argument to show that it’s equal to $a^2b^2$. This isn’t hard — $a(ba)b=a(ab)b=a^2b^2$ — but it needs to be done. Similarly, you need to show that $(ba)^2=b^2a^2$, since you can only say that $(ba)^2=baba$ without using the fact that $a$ and $b$ commute.

Comment: What about the proof of the fact that $a$ and $ab$ commute? Is  that one correct? The first problem is about the fact that $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$ commute. Maybe you didn't see it. If you didn't, is that one correct?

Comment: @AbstraktAlgebra: My eye skipped over the first one when I wrote the answer, but I’d already checked that it was correct. I’ve updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott, cool. Thank you very much.

Comment: @AbstraktAlgebra: You’re welcome!